# Appium Android - How to launch new activity?

Tags: android, selenium, appium

Is there any possibility to switch from one Activity to another Activity with in the application?

Also, Can I know how the get previous test case result through coding?

@Note: I am using TESTNG framework.

Below is the code.

```
// App2 capabilities
    String settingsAppPackageName="com.xxx.xxx.xxxx.dashBoard";
    String settingsAppActivityName="com.xxxx.xxxx.xxx.xxx.DashBoard";


    @Test(priority = 1)
    public void loginTC2(){

        System.out.println("Login 3333::>"+driver.currentActivity());

        if(driver.currentActivity().equals("com.xxx.xxx.xxxx.login.LoginActivity")){

            System.out.println("Login 6666::>"+driver.currentActivity());

            driver.findElement(By.id("com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:id/edtUserName")).sendKeys("xxxx");
            driver.findElement(By.id("com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:id/edtPassword")).sendKeys("xxxx");
            driver.findElement(By.id("com.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx:id/btnLogin")).click();


            // If action is executed then I want to navigate to DashboardActivity
            driver.startActivity(settingsAppPackageName, settingsAppActivityName);

        }else{
            System.out.println("Login 4444::>"+driver.currentActivity());


        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: r u getting any error

Comment: @SaiPawan, org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error occured while starting App. Original error: Activity used to start app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 25.52 seconds

Comment: then it is issue with launching activity only.can u mention the activity in capabilities and try.Find activity using uiautomatorviewer and give that in capabilities

Comment: @SaiPawan, I can launch only initial activity using capabilities? how can I launch the next activity?

Comment: ((AndroidDriver) driver).startActivity(<appPackage>, <appActivity>);   Cross check the activity name once again

Comment: What is the instance of your driver object.is it webdriver or appiumdriver or androiddriver

Comment: I will try and let you know with "((AndroidDriver) driver).startActivity(<appPackage>, <appActivity>); " and I am using androiddriver

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is to test if the activity you want is launching:

`adb shell am start -n <app_package_name>/<full_activity_name>`

If it goes smth like `Starting: Intent {<>}` without errors and you can see app launched on emulator/device, then you I ready to go with Appium.